# Finder always tries to connect to server by default with an Apple ID

Tags: macos, finder, apple-id

Somehow Finder always tries to connect to one server with an Apple ID login name when I do not specifiy the username (i.e. not using `smb://username@serveradress`).

I deleted every occurance of the server's name in Keychain, but Finder still associates this server with the Apple ID. How can I delete this default association?

[image: Login mask with apple id]

P.S.: I do not use this Apple ID anymore on the respective Mac and logged this ID out in iTunes and the App Store. I am using macOS 10.12.6.